# Optimisation : same date x axis on facet_wrap

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, time-series

I have some time series to plot, according to periods going from 1st october to the next 31th september.

So far,I have done this

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

data= (data.table(a=seq(2001,2003,1))  %>%  cross_join(data.table(b=seq(1,12,1))) %>% 
  
  cross_join(data.table(c=seq(1,25,1))) %>% mutate(date=paste0(a,"/",b,"/",c) %>% ymd(),
                                                         variable=rnorm(900),
                                                                                period=case_when(date< ymd("2001/10/01")~ "2001",
                                                                                                 date< ymd("2002/10/01")~ "2002",
                                                                                                 date< ymd("2003/10/01")~ "2003",
                                                                                                 date< ymd("2004/10/01")~ "2004"
                                                                                                 )))[-sample(1:900,400),]

data %>% ggplot() +
  aes(x=date, y=variable, group="") +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~period, nrow=4, scale="free_x")
```

[image: The graph]

I am trying to put the four periods on the same scale (from october to next october). You can see than here, the first and last periods are not on the same scale. I already solved this problem by doing :

1. Transforming the date variable in two factors : one for the period and one for the day-month
2. Add every day-month with null values for my variables (if not, the x scale erases periods without any data)
3. Plot all using `facet_wrap(~period) + aes(x=Day_Month)`

The problem is : this is very tedious, and I've lost the code that does the job.

Does someone has a simpler ggplot solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

1. Add a start (September 30th of one before the first year) and an end line (October 1st of one after the last year) to your data;
2. Then, you cut your date variable into cycles starting at each October 1st, and use that as the facet variable.

There might be smarter ways to accomplish those steps, but below is what I made.

First step:

```
custom_add_row <- function(data, start, ...){
  if(start) {
    fun <- min; k <- -1; day <- "1000-10-01"}
  else {
    fun <- max; k <- +1 ; day <- "1000-9-30"}
  
  add_row(data, date = `year<-`(as.Date(day), year(fun(data$date)) + k), ...)
}

data <- data %>%
  custom_add_row(TRUE, .before = 1) %>%
  custom_add_row(FALSE, .after = nrow(.))
```

Second step:

```
cuts <- unique(year(data$date)) %>% paste0("-10-01") %>% as.Date()

data %>%
  mutate(cicles = cut(date, cuts)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = variable, group = "")) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ cicles, nrow = 4, scales= "free_x") +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b")
```

[image]

Obs: you can change the facet labels by passing a `labels = ...` argument to `cut()`.